# I'm importing a module to another module to make a treeview in tkinter but it is showing me a error NameError: name 'treeview' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, tk-toolkit

I am trying to import a function **add()** from module **tab.py** to a module **treeimport.py** to create a **treeview widget** after **taking data from user in module treeimport.py** and **insert that data in the treeview widget im module tab.py** after a **button ADD is clicked having function add()** but it is showing me a error
`NameError: name 'treeview' is not defined`

**The module tab.py is below**

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

def tree():
    col = ('Website','Email','Password','Security check')
    treeview = ttk.Treeview(window, height=5, show='headings', columns=col)

    treeview.column('Website', width=100, anchor=CENTER)
    treeview.column('Email', width=100, anchor=CENTER)
    treeview.column('Password', width=100, anchor=CENTER)
    treeview.column('Security check', width=100, anchor=CENTER)

    treeview.heading('Website', text='Website')
    treeview.heading('Email', text='Email')
    treeview.heading('Password', text='Password')
    treeview.heading('Security check', text='Security check')

    treeview.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

def add():
    treeview.insert('', 'end',values=(website.get(), email.get(), passwd.get(), 'YES'))

window.mainloop()
```

**And treeimport module is below:**

```
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter import *
from tab import *

ask = Tk()
website = Entry(ask)
email = Entry(ask)
passwd = Entry(ask)

website.pack()
email.pack()
passwd.pack()

rec = Button(ask,text='ADD', command = add())
rec.pack()

ask.mainloop()
```

**Please help me with this problem.**

Comment: What is your directory structure?

Comment: Btw, Star imports `from x import * ` is bad practice, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-import-star-in-python-is-a-bad-idea/

Comment: I have stored both in a same folder named project

Comment: i think the problem is that. your `treeview` is defined inside a function, and it stays in local scope only, so try saying `global treeview` on `tree()` to make it available to the global scope

Comment: I tried `global treeview` but still the same problem

Comment: There are few issues in your code.  First is multiple instances of `Tk()`.  Second you cannot access `website`, `email` and `passwd` inside `add()` function as they are in different scopes.  Even you define `treeview` as global in `tree()`, `treeview` is still undefined if `tree()` is never called.

Comment: I dont see anywhere, were you actually call `tree()` and remove the paranthesis in add for the command arguemnt like `command=add)`. After calling `tree()`, click the button or say `command=lambda:[tree(),add()]`, so both the functions gets executed in one click on the button. Also,
Instead of such menace, i would recommend also trying to make the treeview and adding tvalues inside he treeview in one file and not to import any more files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I have actually reduced the use of importing an external file and compiled it all to a single code, and it works fine. I have used `some.txt` make sure to create such an empty file before trying this code out.

```
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter import *

ask = Tk()

def tree():
    window = Toplevel(ask)
    col = ('Website','Email','Password','Security check')
    treeview = ttk.Treeview(window, height=5, show='headings', columns=col)

    treeview.column('Website', width=100, anchor=CENTER)
    treeview.column('Email', width=100, anchor=CENTER)
    treeview.column('Password', width=100, anchor=CENTER)
    treeview.column('Security check', width=100, anchor=CENTER)

    treeview.heading('Website', text='Website')
    treeview.heading('Email', text='Email')
    treeview.heading('Password', text='Password')
    treeview.heading('Security check', text='Security check')

    treeview.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)    
    
    #opening the list
    open_file = open('some.txt','r')
    lines = open_file.readlines()
    
    #populating the list from the file
    for line in lines:
        treeview.insert('', 'end',values=line)

def store():
    #creating a list of data to be stored in file
    vals = [website.get()+' ',email.get()+' ',passwd.get()+' ','Yes\n']
    lines = open('some.txt','a')
    lines.writelines(vals)
    
    #clearing the entry boxes
    website.delete(0,END)
    email.delete(0,END)
    passwd.delete(0,END)
    
    #setting focus back on first window
    website.focus_force()

website = Entry(ask)
email = Entry(ask)
passwd = Entry(ask)

website.pack()
email.pack()
passwd.pack()

rec = Button(ask,text='ADD', command=store)
rec.pack()

view = Button(ask,text='VIEW',command=tree)
view.pack()

ask.mainloop()
```

some.txt

```
www.google.com something@gmail.com stackoverflow Yes
```

Do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers

Comment: Each time i make a entry with this code, new entry is made in a new treeview window.

Comment: bro please try to make the entry of data in treeview window a backend process.

Comment: what do you mean by backend?

Comment: One point to note, is that once  your treeview window is closed, all the data within it will also be destroyed and hence you might need to store these in some kind of text file or something?

Comment: Thanks bro, I haven't tried it yet but I know this will help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution.
**But i want to make the addition of data in treeview a backend task, which i am searching for.**

```
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

ask = Toplevel()
website = Entry(ask)
email = Entry(ask)
passwd = Entry(ask)

website.pack()
email.pack()
passwd.pack()

col = ('Website','Email','Password','Security check')
treeview = ttk.Treeview(window, height=5, show='headings', columns=col)

treeview.column('Website', width=100, anchor=CENTER)
treeview.column('Email', width=100, anchor=CENTER)
treeview.column('Password', width=100, anchor=CENTER)
treeview.column('Security check', width=100, anchor=CENTER)

treeview.heading('Website', text='Website')
treeview.heading('Email', text='Email')
treeview.heading('Password', text='Password')
treeview.heading('Security check', text='Security check')

treeview.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

def add():
    treeview.insert('', 'end',values=(website.get(), email.get(), passwd.get(), 'YES'))

rec = Button(ask,text='ADD', command = add)
rec.pack()

ask.mainloop()
window.mainloop()
```